# Value_counts() not working in Kaggle notebook but works in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I'm transferring my exploratory data analysis from jupyter notebook (localhost) to kaggle notebook and I keep getting an error about how `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'` even tho the same line of code works in the jupyter notebook.

Here's how it looks on my local jupyter notebook:
[jupyter notebook local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUOGy.png)
But When I try to do the same on Kaggle notebook, here's what happens:
[kaggle notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ4a1.png)

Same code but one works the other doesn't.

Comment: version difference thing. it needs 1.4+. you can either upgrade or for your specific example remove `as_index=False` to make it SeriesGroupBy and `reset_index()` at the end

Comment: Do you happen to know how one would upgrade pandas version in kaggle? I've tried `!pip install pandas --upgrade` but it just keeps on saying 'requirement already satisfied' even though the version is still 1.3.5 and not the 1.4 that's needed. @MustafaAydn

Comment: i would've written the same command, sorry :\ Maybe the pip itself needs updating to see the latest version as 1.4 but not 1.3? could do `!pip install --upgrade pip` but not sure...